# Content change when UIWebView load inside ScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I want to make something like Pulse news when user read the selected news.

When image is not loaded, the space for the image is not yet specified. After the image is loaded, the size of the content also change (the text will be pushed down to make space for the image).

How can i do that?
What i do now is using scroll view, with uiwebview inside it.

```
- (void)loadView
{
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIView *thisView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
contentTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 292, 82)];        
contentThumbnailWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(contentTitleLabel.frame), 292, 0)];

contentDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(contentThumbnailWebView.frame), 292, 23)];

playVideoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(contentThumbnailWebView.frame)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(contentThumbnailWebView.frame)/2, 72, 37)];
[playVideoButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
playVideoButton.hidden = YES;    

contentSummaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(contentDateLabel.frame), 292, 20)];
contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[thisView addSubview:contentScrollView];

[contentScrollView addSubview:contentDateLabel];
    [contentScrollView addSubview:contentTitleLabel];
[contentScrollView addSubview:contentThumbnailWebView];
[contentScrollView addSubview:playVideoButton];
[contentScrollView addSubview:contentSummaryLabel];
//[self.view addSubview:thisView];   
self.view = thisView;
contentThumbnailWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

I've read several topics about this but i still cannot solve it.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {

CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
aWebView.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
fittingSize.width = aWebView.frame.size.width;
frame.size = fittingSize;
aWebView.frame = frame;

NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

[contentDateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(aWebView.frame), 292, 23)];
playVideoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(aWebView.frame)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(aWebView.frame)/2, 72, 37)];
[contentSummaryLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(contentDateLabel.frame), 292, contentSummaryLabel.frame.size.height )];

contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentScrollView.frame.size.width, CGRectGetMaxX(contentSummaryLabel.frame));
```

}

I load jpg image link on it. The image is loaded but the height is not resize correctly. and i also cannot scroll again the scrollView when the webview is loaded.

Below is when i call the image to be loaded

```
- (void) setImageAsThumbnail:(NSString *)imagehumbnailLink
{            
NSURL    *imageURL   = [NSURL URLWithString:imageThumbnailLink];    
NSString *cssString = @"<style type='text/css'>img {width: 292px; height: auto;}</style>";
NSString *myHTMLContent = @"<html><head></head><body><img src='%@'></body></html>";
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cssString,myHTMLContent];
 NSString *imageHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, imageURL];    
contentThumbnailWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[contentThumbnailWebView loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];         
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use UIWebView inside UIScrollView, and because loading HTML is done asynchronously you have to resize the web view and the content size of the scroll view when finished.

```
[webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero]
```

does not work for me either. Instead, in your `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView` you can measure the size of the HTML document by executing a piece of Javascript:

```
NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;";
NSString *heightString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
int height = [heightString intValue]; // HTML document height in pixels
```

In this example, you have to assign the ID 'container' to the top-level element in your HTML (make sure there are no margins around it). This approach works very well for me.