# When does UIWebView finish loading with images?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I tried several methods to detect whether a `UIWebView` did load every content from the source like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19671836/4062660) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916853/4062660).

Here're some typical HTML string to be loaded with UIWebView:

```
<p>some string</p>
<p><img alt="" src="/path/image.png" /></p>
...something like above
```

The below method is always firing too soon before all content (not only the text) that I couldn't get the correct height of the `UIWebView`. (height is shorter than what the webView actually is)

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    // tried to get the content height
    if webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.readyState") == "complete" {
      let height = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight")!
  }
}
```

Where could I get the correct height of the content?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let height = webview.scrollview.contentSize.height
```